# DITA-OT, using custom plugin returns Static error

Tags: plugins, pdf-generation, dita, dita-ot

I made custom plugin in the following URL:
http://dita-generator.elovirta.com/

Then, followed the procedure shown in the following URL:
http://brevitaz.com/dita-jump-start-pdf-plugin-for-customized-pdf-output/

However, there was no custom.xsl as mentioned in step8, I skipped that,
and now, I recieve the error in the screenshot.
[image]

Please someone tell me how to solve this issue.

Comment: You seem to be using DITA-OT 3.2.1. Note that PDF Plugin Generator doesn’t support  3.2.1, the latest supported version is 3.0.

Answer (score 0):

The error says, that attribute sets are missing. You should look up the file(s) that contain(s) the mentioned attribute sets in the original pdf2 plugin. Then, open your `topic2fo_shell_fop.xsl` file and make sure, this/these file(s) ist/are referred. If you have a file with the same name, make sure the original pdf2 file is referred before yours to make sure, your file is overriding it.